# IIS7.5 / Win7 64-bit DefaultAppPool has insufficient security rights 503 Error

Tags: iis, 64-bit, applicationpoolidentity

I have a simple web page I'm trying to publish with IIS 7.5 using the DefaultAppPool.  I add the site using the IIS Services Manager and select the DefaultAppPool.  When I access the page using "Browse Web site" I get a 503 Error "Service Unavailable".  Re-visiting the application Pools I see that the DefaultAppPool has stopped.  Looking at the Windows Event log I see the warning:

> Windows cannot copy file \?\C:\Users\Default\ to location
>   \?\C:\Users\TEMP. This error may be caused by network problems or
>   insufficient security rights.

Troubleshooting this issue I discovered that if I change from ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem the page then displays correctly.  I'd prefer to use the applicationPoolIdentity if possible.

Searching the internet hasn't yielded any definite answers but there was an interesting comment asking if Win7 64-bit was used.  I set up a Win7 32-bit VM with IIS configured the same way as on my Win7 64-bit machine and the web site worked with ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I'd prefer to deploy my app on 64-bit if possible.

So the question finally is:  How do I get my IIS 7.5 web site to work with ApplicationPoolIdentity while using Win7 64-bit?